# bootstrap 3.3.7 modal not displaying the html

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

i have the following code and the $('.modal).modal('show') seems to add the html to the DOM but is not being displayed.  I noticed the opacity has changed to .5

Here is the code

```
<div class="modal fade" id="editMezalta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
<div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <form>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
                    <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be working no problem. Have you remembered to include the relevant Bootstrap JS and CSS files?

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<button data-target="#editMezalta" data-toggle="modal">Open Modal</button>

<div class="modal fade" id="editMezalta" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="exampleModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="exampleModalLabel">New message</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="recipient-name" class="control-label">Recipient:</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control" id="recipient-name">
          </div>
          <div class="form-group">
            <label for="message-text" class="control-label">Message:</label>
            <textarea class="form-control" id="message-text"></textarea>
          </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary">Send message</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-Tc5IQib027qvyjSMfHjOMaLkfuWVxZxUPnCJA7l2mCWNIpG9mGCD8wGNIcPD7Txa" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```